# AngularJS change css after comparison to a self-sorted string

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, if-statement

I have small question about angularjs controllers
suppose i have a div tag that display the parameters like this

```
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="table-cell" id="account">
 {{x.accountNumber}}</div>
```

Account number is a random number stored like this

```
accountNumber="214323"
```

and the sorted string is :

```
sortedNumber="122334"
```

Here is the thing i want to do:

sort it in a increasing order and compare the 2 number

if they are same i would put the background color to light blue.

if not keep it like that way.

My question is how to sort and compare them and then change background color of div tag to blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure how you should go about with sorting the numbers. 
When you figure that out, use `ng-class` inside your div tags.

like this:

**Css**

```
.blueDiv{
    backgroud-color: lightblue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="table-cell" id="account" 
     ng-class="{blueDiv: accountNumber == sortedNumber}">
 {{x.accountNumber}}
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you could use a function in javascript `split("")` it into an array, `.sort(function(a, b){return a - b})` the result, then `.join("")` the sorted arra to create a single number.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am trying to get the sorted number render on angular model so that i can compare two number, i use a    `ng-click=sort()` to call the function that return a sortedNumber to  `ng-class`

Comment: BTW it is possible to put all operation in one row so that to looks like `sortedNumber= accountNumber.split("").sort().join("")`